# Extracting the top 5 maximum values in excel within a range

Tags: excel-formula

I would like to create a formula that returns the top 5 longest running projects excluding those on Phase 3.

```
Project Name  Days  Phase
   A            B   C 
Project 1      38   1
Project 2      35   1
Project 3      40   2
Project 4      32   2
Project 5      41   2
Project 6      35   2
Project 7      42   3
Project 8      44   3
```

I tried adapting a formula that was posted here, but instead of ignoring all phase 3 projects, I get value of `#N/A`.

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$9,MATCH(1,INDEX(($C$3:$C$9<3)* ($B$2:$B$9=LARGE($B$2:$B$9,ROWS(G$1:G1)))*(COUNTIF(G$1:G1,$A$3:$A$9)=0),),0),0)
```

This is what I get

```
 G
#N/A
#N/A
Project 5
Project 3
Project 1
```

Comment: Is using `Pivot Table` an option for you? and what if there are multiple projects having same days within the top 5? Do you want to show all projects that have days in the top 5 (which could be more than 5 projects) or just want to show 5 projects that have the highest days (which could be less than 5 projects)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put the condition `($C$3:$C$9<3)` inside the `LARGE`-function and adapt all ranges to same length, then you should get the desired result.

The corrected formula should look like this: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> **ARRAY-FORMULA**

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$9,MATCH(1,INDEX( ($B$2:$B$9=LARGE(($C$2:$C$9<3)*($B$2:$B$9),ROWS(G$1:G1)))*(COUNTIF(G$1:G1,$A$2:$A$9)=0),),0),0)
```

Apply to cell `G2`.

**EDIT**

If you want the formula changable between minimum and maximum values, you have to put the condition into an `IF` statement. This filters the `0`-results of the condition which would interfere with `SMALL`.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> **ARRAY-FORMULA**

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$9,MATCH(1,INDEX( ($B$2:$B$9=SMALL(IF($C$2:$C$9<3,$B$2:$B$9),ROWS(G$1:G1)))*(COUNTIF(G$1:G1,$A$2:$A$9)=0),),0),0)
```

In this formula u can put in `LARGE` or `SMALL` and get the desired results.

Comment: it worked, but just out of curiosity, what if I wanted the 5 shortest project excluding phase 3? I tried switching LARGE for SMALL and the array formula didn't work. Anyway, thank you.